# Rails "where" method to find parent by child attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails app where I'm trying to create a list of parent classes based on the date of their child classes.

right now I have:

```
orders = Order.where("order_reminders.date < ?", 1.month.from_now)
```

But I'm receiving an error.

"no such column: order_reminders.date"

I'm sure my problem is with my query but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use methods like `references`, `joins`, `includes` or `eager_load` depending on what you need.  The simplest way to determine what to select is to go to the [documentation/api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-eager_load) and read them.

As for the answer, if `order_reminders` is defined as an association in `Order`, just use `joins` which uses an `INNER JOIN` by default, meaning it won't return `orders` without `order_reminders` which is most probably what you want when you're searching for something.

```
Order.joins(:order_reminders).where('order_reminders.date < ?', 1.month.from_now)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is order_reminders another table in your app?

If `order has_many order_reminders` then try this query

```
Order.joins(:order_reminders).where("order_reminders.date < ?", 1.month.from_now)
```