# How do I find a Record when the match column is two tables away?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `InstanceUser` model that belongs to a `User` model through `user_id`.

`User` has multiple `User::Email`s.

`User::Email`s each have an email property.

Given an email address, how do I find the `InstanceUser`, if any, such that `instance_user.user.emails` would contain `User::Email` with that email address?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940206/rails-where-method-to-find-parent-by-child-attribute

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Gabbar I've posted my current solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `has_many through` to your UserInstance:

```
class UserInstance < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :emails, through: :user, class_name: 'User::Email'
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

You can then query UserInstance using the following query:

```
UserInstance.includes(:emails).where('emails.email = ?', email)
```

Comment: @Dexter Leng let me know if you have any problems with this!

Answer (score 0):

```
User.joins(:instance_users, :emails).exists?(
    user_emails: {email: @email}, 
    instance_users: {instance: @current_instance }
)
```

This seems to work

Comment: Replace `exists?` to `where`

Comment: You want `instance_user` or `User` ?

Comment: Currently I only need to check if the `InstanceUser` exists so this is fine. But if need the `InstanceUser`, how would I do it? `User` is the model that connects `InstanceUser` and `User::Email`.